# Saving a CSR matrix: memory size increasing

Tags: python, matrix, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have to work with a sparse matrix saved as .mtx format, name it matrix.mtx, which takes 270MB in memory.
When I load it, transform it to CSR format (I need to do arithmetic operations on it) and resave it, the size strangely increases !

```
from scipy import sparse, io
m = io.mmread('matrix.mtx')
m = m.tocsr()
io.mmwrite('matrix_csr.mtx', m)
```

Now matrix_csr.mtx takes 692 MB in memory. I tried different options, like applying methods tocoo(), tolil(), tocsc() on the CSR matrix, but everytime I save it the resulting matrix is still 692MB in memory.

Does anyone know how I can save my CSR matrix so that it takes only 270MB in memory again ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried comparing the file metadata using `mminfo`?

Comment: Yes, and both of them give the same metadata: (414908, 4713, 22138810, 'coordinate', 'real', 'general')

Comment: I think I have found the problem: when I call io.mmread and tocsr(), the resulting matrix is of dtype np.float64. But when I convert the dtype to np.int8 and then save the matrix with io.mmwrite, I get back an .mtx file of size 270MB. In my case, this is not a problem because I am working with a binary matrix so there is no lack of precision when using int8 instead of float64.